# How to get only the rendered text of a Text Node?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating a little webextension which modifies a webpage depending on the text. As an example of my problem here is some code which has a tree walker grabs all text nodes on a page:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
  { acceptNode: () => {return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;} },
  false
);

while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
  let x = treeWalker.currentNode.data;
  //do something with x
}
```

Unfortunately, x will have all of the text in the node, even if it isn't shown on the webpage.

What I want is something like treeWalker.currentNode.innerText, but that is undefined for text nodes. Does anyone know how to get only the text shown to the user for a text node?

Example: If a webpage has the node with the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <script type="text/x-config">
    {
      "setObject": -1
    }
  </script>
    <span>Quiz</span>
```

with associated CSS:

```
script {
    display: none;
}
```

Then the text content of the respective text node (minus extra spaces and line breaks) is returned as "{ "setObject": -1 } Quiz". However, the only thing that is rendered to the user is "Quiz". Given the respective text node, how do I get only the rendered text?

Comment: What's an example of text node content that isn't shown to the user?

Comment: Are you trying to get "visible" text in the sense that the data is being hidden by CSS? (like `text-overflow` rules)?

Comment: Added an example for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we have a problem.

If you are using a new browser you should be able to the innerText, but if you are not you have to use textContent.
The problem of textContent is that it gets the content of all elements including  and  and textContent is not aware of style so it will return hidden events.

I guess the way to go is to replace the filter with `NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT` and get the `Element.innerHTML`.

So try it:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    { acceptNode: (node) => {  return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;} },
false
);

while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    let x = treeWalker.currentNode.innerHTML;
    //do something with x
}
```

Comment: I tried using innerText on the most recent version of chrome, and it always returned undefined for the text nodes. Also, in the scenario you proposed I am no longer looking at text nodes so innerText should work. Why would I use innerHTML and not innerText?

Comment: Well, innerText is a property of Node as you can see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

And have some compatibility problems as innerHTML will work no matter the browser.

Comment: Element is a descent of a Node so it also inherits innerText.

Comment: I know that,  what i meant is that innerText as aproperty of node should work for you even before of changing the Filter, if it is not,  you should try innerHtml. Because it is compatible with almost all versions of browsers, but you can do as you like.